# angular and sass - change a variable value at the component level

Tags: angular, sass

I have an app that will display the same component in two tabs. I'm using a sass theme with variables. I'd like the colors to be different on these tabs and this is controlled byt the `$accent` variable.

The implementation below seems to work when the page appears. First tab is of the correct color and then when I go to the second tab it is also of correct color. However when I go back to the first tab, it appears with the second color and both tabs stay with the second color from then on.

```
class BaseComponent {
    //some logic
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-first',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    templateUrl: './base.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./first.component.scss']
})
export class FirstComponent extends BaseComponent {
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-second',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    templateUrl: './base.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./second.component.scss']
})
export class SecondComponent extends BaseComponent {
}
```

Here the `first.component.scss` file:

```
$accent: #46ADD7;
@import "~my/theme";
```

Here is the `second.component.scss` file:

```
$accent: #46ADD7;
@import "~my/theme";
```